# Including a NuGet package in an Azure function written in the Portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created a new Azure function in the portal, and wanted to use the `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet package.  Given that the default template is created with:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
```

I thought I could do this:

```
#r "WindowsAzure.Storage"
```

However, when I do, I get the error:

```
[Error] run.csx(2,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'WindowsAzure.Storage' could not be found
```

I can't see anywhere else that `Newtonsoft.Json` is being referenced.

How can I include this NuGet package in my function (without building this is VS or VS Code and deploying it). Also, what, exactly does the `#r` directive do, if not bring in external libraries and packages?

Comment: Every time I have recently tried to use to create Functions in the portal I ran into some issue with nuget references. My advice: To make your life easier - also in regards to IntelliSense etc. - do NOT create Functions in the portal but start right away with a proper IDE such as VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is correction in namespace

**#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"**

and not
  **#r "WindowsAzure.Storage"**

You can refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#binding-to-arguments

Comment: Thanks. In fact the documentation is a little further down that article for anyone lookingat this later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#importing-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

Ok so everytime i create a Function app i mostly use VS Code or Visual Studio just for the intellisense and easiness of work. To add a nuget from the Azure portal

1. Click on `View Files` and add a `function.proj`

[image]

2. Now add the below piece of code with any nuget do you need.

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3"/>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

upon saving this you should see the console update stating that the packages are getting installed. This really isn't well documented in the microsoft docs

Answer (score -1):

Try with   #r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

You can also upload a custom dll into the function app by Kudu tools. And then you can refer the dll by #r "path to dll"